# Find multiple ranges in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a capacity planning worksheet for air routes, which includes the amount of seats to a destination in a given time period. There can be more than one time period because there are gaps in the schedule, or the amount of seats changes. This would create two "ranges" for which new flights have to be made.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GCfHGcD.jpg]

The picture shows a small portion of the Excel sheet. The red shows the first range from 15-APR to 22-APR and the blue shows the second range from 6-May to 13-May.

I can find the first range by finding the first and last populated cell in the row. I do this by using `.End(xlToRight)` and `.End(xlToLeft)`.

I then use the found coordinate to give a variable the value in cell `(4, y)`. Something like this:

```
lCol = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).End(xlToRight).Column
fCol = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 58).End(xlToLeft).Column
EffDate = Cells(4, fCol)
DiscDate = Cells(4, lCol)
```

The macro loops through the worksheet and adds a flight per row to another worksheet. Ideally I want to create a If-Else scenario to check if there are multiple "periods" in a row. I do not want to join two ranges together.

Comment: Is your question more about location specific headers, or, how to join ranges together...or both?

Comment: `MATCH` would help if you are trying to locate a header, something like `match(EffDate+7,range("1:1"),false)` would match the next week

Comment: *"what would be a method to solve my problem?"* Doesn't work as a standalone question - please elaborate.

Comment: The macro loops through the document and adds a flight per row to another worksheet. Ideally I want to create a If-Else scenario where it checks if there are multiple "periods" in a row. I do not want to join two ranges together.